# Create directory but only when not running from floppy

Tags: c++, dos

I'm trying to get my application to create a directory if it doesn't exist, but only if the application isn't running from a floppy drive.  I'm making the assumption that drives A: and B: are floppies.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
char dir[_MAX_DIR];
char filen[_MAX_FNAME];
char ext[_MAX_EXT];
char SourcePath[_MAX_PATH];

_splitpath( ProgramPath, drive, dir, filen, ext );
strcpy( SourcePath, drive );
strcat( SourcePath, dir );
strcat( SourcePath, "SYSBAK" );

if ( toupper( drive[0] ) != 'A' || toupper( drive[0] != 'B' ) {
    if ( !FolderExist( SourcePath ) ) {
        try {
            _mkdir( SourcePath );
        }
        catch( ... ) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if ( stricmp( drive, "A:" ) != 0 || stricmp( drive, "B:" ) != 0 ) {
```

and:

```
if ( !(stricmp( drive, "A:" ) == 0) || !(stricmp( drive, "B:" ) == 0) ) {
```

and yet when I compile and run from a floppy, the directory still gets created.  I've confirmed using `printf` that `drive[0]` is indeed equal to A when running from floppy drive A:.  `ProgramPath` is defined earlier in the application as `argv[0]`.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?  What is the correct code?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Unrelated: `toupper( drive[0] )` once, store the result in a variable, use the variable in the `if` rather than repeating yourself. A smart compiler will perform this optimization for you, but the real concern is a future change to the code that only updates one of the `toupper`s.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag, since this looks like C code. If this is actually C++, then feel free to switch to the C++ tag. But don't tag both, because you're writing one program and compiling it with one compiler, which means it's written in one language, not two different ones.

Comment: `toupper(drive[0]) != 'A' || toupper(drive[0]) != 'B'` (that is always true as `'A' != 'B'`) -> `toupper(drive[0]) != 'A' && toupper(drive[0]) != 'B'`

Comment: @user4581301 Good catch. No pun intended.

Comment: Side note: I've found checking if the folder exists before making a folder to be useless, one of the first things the folder checks is whether the folder exists or not, so you're paying twice, and some jerk could come along and add the folder between the two calls. Harmless, but a waste of time.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo

It's my understanding that ```try``` and ```catch``` are strictly C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews DOS.

Comment: @Jarod42 that worked!  I added ```drive[0] = toupper( drive[0] );``` and then used ```if ( drive[0] != 'A' && drive[0] != 'B' )``` and the program executes as expected.  Thanks!

How do I mark yours as the answer?

Comment: @CharlieDobson: `!(d == 'A' || d == 'B')` is `d != 'A' && d != 'B'` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 even better

Comment: "*I'm making the assumption that drives A: and B: are floppies*" - don't assume anything. **ASK THE OS**, such as with [`GetDriveType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) on Windows. You say you are coding for DOS, but is that really true? Or are you just running your code inside of a Console window running on Windows? The Console can run DOS apps, but DOS and Console are NOT the same thing. Windows hasn't been based on true DOS for 20-30 years now. Console apps have full access to the Win32 API

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I am certain I'm coding for DOS, not the Windows CLI.  This is part of a passion project that I always wanted to do back in the day, and that is to write a suite of utilities for DOS and Windows 3.1x.  Once completed, I intend on sharing this with the retro-community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *"typos"*, in particular, your `||` should be `&&`:

```
toupper(drive[0]) != 'A' && toupper(drive[0]) != 'B'
```

which is equivalent to

```
!(toupper(drive[0]) == 'A' || toupper(drive[0]) == 'B')
```